# SparkFun 9DoF Razor IMU (SEN-14001)

Tags: ros, imu, sensor, razor-imu-9dof

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS driver for the Razor IMU (http://wiki.ros.org/razor_imu_9dof) states to work with the versions SEN-10125 and SEN-10736. However, SparkFun only sells the new version SEN-14001 (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14001). Does anyone know if the ROS driver still works for this version or if alternatively if I can by an SEN-10736 somewhere.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261398/sparkfun-9dof-razor-imu-(sen-14001)/) by [Markus_](https://answers.ros.org/users/30304/markus_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-05-10**:
The ros nodes needs the AHRS firmware on the IMU. Its [probably not yet ported.](https://github.com/Razor-AHRS/razor-9dof-ahrs/issues/57)

**Comment by [Markus_](https://answers.ros.org/users/30304/markus_/) on 2017-05-10**:
Thanks for the hint.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-05-10**:
Btw if you are looking for a cheap IMU for use with ROS, maybe try [TinkerForge IMU Brick 2.0](https://discourse.ros.org/t/tractobots-my-attempts-at-field-robots/1486/32). But I have not tested it yet.

**Comment by [Markus_](https://answers.ros.org/users/30304/markus_/) on 2017-05-10**:
Looks promising. I'll let you know if I opt for this one and get it to run.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-05-15**:
Got one, with all the leds it looks a bit like a Christmas tree. Software installation is complicated (requires a daemon). Mounted it on the same bot as my razor. Looking forward to compare.

**Comment by [Markus_](https://answers.ros.org/users/30304/markus_/) on 2017-05-16**:
Did you use this package? https://github.com/gus484/ros-tinkerforge_sensors

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-05-16**:
So far I have only used the TinkerForge IMU standalone, without ROS. I'm not 100% happy with this package as the covariance matrix is fixed to 0.1 for all values.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-05-16**:
First result: IMU Brick can give reasonable values without calibration, the razor IMU needs way more attention here. However this comes with higher currents, Razor: 40mA, Brick v2: 70mA.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-05-19**:
ok Here is a [plot of razor imu compared to the Tinkerforge while slowly turning the robot](http://vontaene.de/ros/razor_imu_vs_tinkerforge_imu2/razor_imu_vs_tinkerforge_brick2_orientation_z_turn.png). No suprises so far. The Tinkerforge has a good performance regarding that it is uncalibrated.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-05-19**:
Here the awesome part, I tried to fool both imu with a magnet. Result is [little to no visible change in the tinkerforge orientation.](http://vontaene.de/ros/razor_imu_vs_tinkerforge_imu2/razor_imu_vs_tinkerforge_brick2_magnetic_distortion.png). Looks like the Brick is a keeper.

**Comment by [Boregard](https://answers.ros.org/users/33549/boregard/) on 2018-03-07**:
Hi
thanks for the update. I got some different issues. First SparkFunMPU9250-DMP.cpp was missing. Downloaded from sparkfun git.
But now I get some compilation errors in Arduino IDE. -> sketchbook/libraries/MPU9250DMP/SparkFunMPU9250-DMP.cpp:532: Nicht definierter Verweis auf `mpu_set_lpf'
Br Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi There,

I'm also trying to setup the razor_imu_9dof node with the new sparkfun board, I've found a fork of the original firmware that supports the new 14001 based board here:

https://github.com/lebarsfa/razor-9dof-ahrs

To be honest though, I haven't managed to get it working 100% yet but it's closer than anything else I've found so far. It's outputting the linear and angular acceleration values correctly but the orientation estimate seems a bit buggy. I'm working on this at the moment so I'll post any progress I make.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2017-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-11-29**:
I don't think that this is a good place for reporting updates, try [discourse](https://discourse.ros.org/) instead.

**Comment by [lebarsfa](https://answers.ros.org/users/32917/lebarsfa/) on 2017-12-08**:
Just a last comment : I think now I have corrected most of the problems on https://github.com/lebarsfa/razor-9dof-ahrs, check latest version and see if it is better...

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2017-12-09**:
Great news, I'll pull the latest version and let you know how I get on early next week. Thanks for sharing your work.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2017-12-20**:
It's working! Thanks for your help lebarsfa. I really think your updated code should get pushed back to the original repo, since no-one can use the original firmware with the hardware that is available now!

**Comment by [lebarsfa](https://answers.ros.org/users/32917/lebarsfa/) on 2017-12-20**:
OK, so I will try to propose a pull request to both https://github.com/Razor-AHRS/razor-9dof-ahrs and https://github.com/KristofRobot/razor_imu_9dof.